# Git Clone from SSH Repository

Tags: ssh, git

I used to be able to clone from my personal git repository but now i seem to be running into an error.

```
user:dev.site.com mikesilvis$ git clone { my ssh directory }
server@ipaddress's password: 

remote: Counting objects: 3622, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2718/2718), done.
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.  
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

It seems to be working however while I push files to the repository.

Comment: What happens if you download a copy of the repository and try cloning it locally? (i.e. using a local path instead of an ssh URL) If it works, I'd wonder whether the git installation on the remote server might be at fault.

Comment: > fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
git-pack-objects died with error
```

suggests that there's something wrong with the remote. Can you ssh into the remote and run `git fsck`? If that finds any errors, you may have a faulty CPU, RAM or storage device (believe me or not but git is really good at finding those). Another thing to check is to make sure that both the local system and remote systems are not running out of storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the permissions?

For the git user (normally called git)?

See this

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether your shell initialization doesn't generate any output in non-interactive mode. This is a typical reason for example that scp doesn't work (you could check if it does).